# sql programming joining of four tables

Tags: sql

select e.empno, e.ename, e.sal, d.deptno, d.dname, l.loc_id, l.loc_name, a.add1, a.add2, a.pin from emp e, address a, location l, dept d on inner join emp,deptno and on inner join emp,address and inner join dept,location having a.add2=rp and l.loc_name=kolkata;

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please read a SQL tutorial on how to properly write a join.

Answer (score 2):

```
select e.empno, e.ename, e.sal, d.deptno, d.dname, l.loc_id, l.loc_name, a.add1, a.add2, a.pin 
from emp e
inner join dept d on d.deptno=e.deptno
inner joint location l on l.loc_id=d.loc_id
inner join address a on a.adress_id=e.address_id
where a.add2 = 'rp' and l.loc_name='kolkata';
```

Did you meant somethig like this?